# Using custom post type parent as slug

Tags: custom-post-types, slug, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using the plugin 'Types Custom Post Type' to create custom post types (I know it's pretty easily done through `functions.php` but I was feeling a bit lazy!).

Basically, I'm looking to have the following format for pages:

`/wellbean-cottage/` - the main page for a house

`/wellbean-cottage/things-to-do/` - a child page with information about the house

I thought the best option would be to create a different post type for these sub-pages, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to add the house slug beforehand. Does anyone have any idea how it can be set up to work like this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you link the plugin? I couldnt find what you wrote in  the plugin repository

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood you right, but there's an option when registering the custom post type:

```
register_post_type( 'your_cpt_name', array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => true )
) );
```